# reading and writing data with a text file in java

Tags: java, database, file, server

I am trying to create a command that allows the user who is logged in to edit their username and password and then save the updated details. Currently the updating details seem to work but when i write the details to the new file all the other data (other users details) from the old file are erased and only the current user updated details come up in the file. Here is my code:

```
public class UpdateDetailsCommand implements Command{
private BufferedWriter out;
private BufferedReader in;
private MsgSvrConnection conn;

public void execute() throws IOException
  {

    if (conn.getCurrentUser() != null) {

        String username1 = conn.getCurrentUser();
        String password1 = conn.getServer().getUserPassword(username1);

        BufferedReader fr = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("pwd.txt"));
        PrintWriter fw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("pwd.txt", true));
        String line;

        String username = in.readLine();
        String password = in.readLine();

        if (password != null && username != null)   {

            while ((line = fr.readLine()) != null) {
            if (line.contains(username1) && line.contains(password1) ){
                    line = line.replace(username1, username);   
                    line = line.replace(password1, password);
    fw.println(line);
}           
}
                fr.close();
                fw.close();


                out.write("done");  
                out.flush();
            }

        }

    }

public  UpdateDetailsCommand(BufferedReader in, BufferedWriter out, 
          MsgSvrConnection serverConn)
{
this.out = out;
this.in = in;
this.conn = serverConn;
```

}
}

Im guessing the way i read and write the file is not quite correct, but i am not sure what i did wrong here.

Comment: You do not check the results of `.delete()` and `.renameTo()`... Not that this is your problem, but they can fail.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to write a text file (line structure) use a PrintWriter.

```
PrintWriter fw = new PrintWriter( new FileWriter("temp_pwd.txt", true) );
```

The while loop must not contain close() - this terminates everything.

```
while ((line = fr.readLine()) != null) {
            if (line.contains(username1))
                line = line.replace(username1, username);
            if (line.contains(password1))
                line = line.replace(password1, password);
            fw.println(line);
} // close while block here

fr.close();
fw.close();
```

You should also make sure to change a single line only. Chances are small that the password occurs more than once, but it's possible.

```
   if (line.contains(username1) && line.contains(password1) ){
        line = line.replace(username1, username);   
        line = line.replace(password1, password);
   }
```

Moreover, contains() is not a good way for testing. What if you have one user

```
   josephus,Oki987e3
```

and another one

```
   joseph,Oki987e3
```

and joseph changes his username and password??

Comment: thanks, ive made the changes and now it seems it saves the data, but it saves it all in one line without spaces and due to this i am unable to read usernames and passwords. The way pwd file is structured is that every username and password is stored on a new line and the format is username=password ( "=" are being added correctly at the moment).

Comment: Recommended to use a PrintWriter. Don't try to write line ends manually. - See update in answer.

Comment: Also, the `close()` calls should be in a finally block.

Comment: @DavidConrad And try/resources, and more.

Comment: @laune ihave made further changes (updated the post) and it now writes each line. The issue i've encountered now is that, i've tried updating the second line "red=bean" to "red=Bean", when the file updated i got the following result "red=beanred=Bean" so it just seem to have added the input to the old data and did not replace it.

Comment: This is not possible if you have the code as shown. Is there an additional fw.write() method call somewhere?

Comment: @laune hm, there is not. Shouldnt username1 be replaced with username by using this code?

Comment: Yes, if it is in the old file. - Make sure the output file does not exist - otherwise data will be appended. Perhaps better to use false for the append argument in new FileWriter since you are recreating the entire file, and so you can and should overwrite an existing file.

Comment: @laune changing it to false make it so just the new input data is saved and everything else is gone. Perhaps it is possible to somehow remove the old data from "red=beanred=Bean" and just keep the new data?

Comment: If you overwrite the file it will be gone. Or use an OS command to remove the file before you retry.

Comment: @laune i've made some further changes to just overwrite the old file (updated post). What happens now is that whatever the input for the new user and pwd is saved on a new line in the document, meaning i can actually use that for a log in, but, the old user and pwd is still in the file also. So it saves the new data below the old one, anyway to remove the old data?

Comment: You can't read and write a sequential text file changing one or more lines in one go. You have to create a copy (with those changes) and replace the input file with the output file - as you had it before. Then, don't open the output with append set to true.